# flutter - Comparing two lists of objects isn't working

Tags: flutter, dart

I've two lists of objects that i wanna compare, a and b:

```
final dia = DateTime(2017, 9, 7, 17, 30);
final ppp = Parcela("1", 225.5, dia, null, 1, false, false);
final ppp2 =Parcela("1", 225, dia.add(const Duration(days: 3)), null, 1, false, false);
final ppp3 =Parcela("1", 225, dia.add(const Duration(days: 3)), null, 1, false, false);
List<Parcela> a = [ppp,ppp2,];
List<Parcela> b = [ppp, ppp3];
```

Both of them are equal, but when i try to check it with the functions bellow i get false on response:

```
print(a.every(b.toSet().contains));
print(listEquals(a, b));
```

I tried also "quiver" and "collection" libraries from pub dev but the result is the same

The Parcela model:

```
class Parcela {
  String id;
  double valor;
  DateTime dataPagamento;
  DateTime dataPago;
  int status;
  int ref;

  Parcela(String id, double valor, DateTime dataPagamento, DateTime dataPago,
      int ref, bool pago, bool atraso) {
    this.id = id;
    this.valor = valor;
    this.dataPagamento = dataPagamento;
    this.dataPago = this.dataPago;
    this.status = _getStatus(pago, atraso);
    this.ref = this.ref;
  }
  int _getStatus(bool pago, bool atraso) {
    if (pago) {
      if (atraso) {
        return 3;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    } else {
      if (atraso) {
        return 2;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit1:**

I've tried Dan James suggestion but my class isn't final as his, so i've removed "final" from name attribute:

```
class Person extends Equatable {
   Person(this.name);

   String name;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name];

}
```

the new test vars:

```
Person p = Person("name");
Person p2 = Person("name2");
Person p3 = Person("tobias");

List<Person> aa = [p, p2];
List<Person> bb = [p, p2..name = "teste"];
List<Person> cc = [p, p3];
```

but when i test the lists:

```
var filtered_lst =List.from(aa.where((value) => !bb.contains(value)));
print(filtered_lst);
print(listEquals(aa, bb));
print(listEquals(aa, cc));
```

the console returns this:

```
I/flutter (12746): []
I/flutter (12746): true
I/flutter (12746): false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ppp2 does not equal ppp3 because they are two different instances of a class. You could override the '==' operator to check if each field is the same. ie. ppp2.id == ppp3.id.

eg/ (taken from equatable docs but this is vanillar dart)

```
class Person {
  const Person(this.name);

  final String name;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
    identical(this, other) ||
    other is Person &&
    runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
    name == other.name;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;
}
```

Or look into the equatable package which does this for you. https://pub.dev/packages/equatable

Straight from the equatable docs:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Person extends Equatable {
  const Person(this.name);

  final String name;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name];

}
```

Comment: can you add a sample code to your answer?

Comment: your solution doesn't work:

Person p = Person("name");

Person p2 = Person("name2");

List<Person> aa = [p, p2];

List<Person> bb = [p, p2..name = "teste"];

print(listEquals(aa, bb));

returns true

Comment: It's returning `true` in the first comparison because when you do `p2..name = "teste"` you're also modifying the `p2` object inside `aa`, so `aa` and `bb` will be true.

Comment: Is there any way of generating a copy of another list that doesn't point to the same address of memory?

Comment: using the spread operator is an easy way to create a new list. eg/. `List list2 = [...list1];`

Comment: i've tried your way of copying the list (and many more), till i found one that worked. This answer per se didn't solve the problem but like it helped me finding the problems on the i've checked it. Gonna post the full solution to help others

Answer (score 0):

Using the library [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) from Dan James answer:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class Parcela extends Equatable {
  String id;
  double valor;
  DateTime dataPagamento;
  DateTime dataPago;
  int status;
  int ref;

  Parcela(String id, double valor, DateTime dataPagamento, DateTime dataPago,
      int ref, bool pago, bool atraso) {
    this.id = id;
    this.valor = valor;
    this.dataPagamento = dataPagamento;
    this.dataPago = this.dataPago;
    this.status = _getStatus(pago, atraso);
    this.ref = this.ref;
  }
  int _getStatus(bool pago, bool atraso) {
    if (pago) {
      if (atraso) {
        return 3;
      } else {
        return 2;
      }
    } else {
      if (atraso) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id,valor,dataPagamento,];
}
```

The only way of copying a list that doesn't point to the same memory address:

```
List<Parcela> copyParcelas(List<Parcela> list) {
  List<Parcela> copyList = [];
  for (var item in list) {
    List<bool> _status = pagoAtraso(item.status);
    Parcela betItems = Parcela(item.id, item.valor, item.dataPagamento,
        item.dataPago, item.ref, _status[0], _status[1]);
    copyList.add(betItems);
  }
  return copyList;
}
```

Then the check to return the list items that changed:

```
List<Parcela> editarParcelas(List<Parcela> parcelas, List<Parcela> original){
    return filteredlst = parcelas.toSet().difference(original.toSet()).toList();
}
```